# Defining invalid regions of VRT file with rasterio in a way that allows windowing

Tags: raster, rasterio, masking, vrt, invalid-data

I'm using a VRT file to represent a bunch of individual map tiles as one big image. I noticed that some of the data is invalid but not marked as such (via the invalid data value). I'd like to define these regions as invalid using a file (e.g. a shapefile) in a way that would allow me to call `dataset.read(..., masked=True)` and get a masked NumPy array that masks out both data that has the dataset's invalid data value, and data that I manually define to be invalid in my file.

I found [an example](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html) in the `rasterio` documentation using `Fiona` to load a shapefile and use it to mask some data. I figured that would be useful, so I built a shapefile with my invalid regions as polygons. I'm now having trouble reading from my VRT file with these shapes masked out. I've got the following code:

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
import fiona

VRT_FILE = "/path/to/my/vrt/file.vrt"
SHAPE_FILE = "/path/to/my/shape/file.shp"

with rasterio.open(VRT_FILE) as dataset, fiona.open(SHAPE_FILE, "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]
    masked_data = rasterio.mask.mask(dataset, shapes, invert=True)
    # Error thrown on line above.
```

but this throws the error `MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (216640, 282250) and data type bool` because the `rasterio.mask.mask` call is trying to load the whole (huge) VRT file, not a small section of it as I would like.

It seems there is apparently no way to define a `Window` object with the `mask` method. Until now (before starting to use shapefiles to define invalid data) I've been reading the dataset with `dataset.read(... window=Window(...))`, which lets me define a window to avoid reading the whole (huge) dataset at once. I'd like to do this for my shape-masked data too.

I have two questions:

- Is my approach to defining these invalid regions - i.e. with a shapefile - reasonable? Or is there a canonical way? Ideally I'd like to avoid having to manually write the original data back to disk with these regions set to the dataset's real invalid data value, since it's 50 GB compressed. Perhaps there's a way to define this invalid data while generating the VRT file in the first place?
- If my approach is indeed reasonable, then is there a way to create a `DatasetReader`-like object that supports `.read(...)` with a window parameter, using data masked from my shapefile?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please restructure the question so that there's only one question asked.